# Why wasn't there a June 2014 site evaluation?

Tags: support

Our last four site self-evaluations were 3 months apart:

1. [Jun 2013 Site Self-Evaluation](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/lets-get-critical-jun-2013-site-self-evaluation) (posted on 2013-06-25)
2. [Sep 2013 Site Self-Evaluation](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1078/lets-get-critical-sep-2013-site-self-evaluation) (posted on 2013-09-23)
3. [Dec 2013 Site Self-Evaluation](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1123/lets-get-critical-dec-2013-site-self-evaluation) (posted on 2013-12-23)
4. [Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1164/lets-get-critical-mar-2014-site-self-evaluation) (posted on 2014-03-23)

So I thought we'd have another one toward the end of June, but we didn't.  It's now the end of July, more than four months since the last one was posted.  Has something changed?

EDIT: It's now September 2014.  Will we have a site evaluation this month?  Are they now twice a year instead of quarterly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was brought up recently [on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237588/215040), where an employee wrote:

> The current policy is that site self-evaluations are now on a 180 day schedule (so, basically 6 months). We had discussed some measure of staggering but I do not believe that was implemented.

So apparently it *did* change, although there was no announcement as far as I'm aware.  We should have another site evaluation this month, starting September 19 at 3:01.